# how do I send an API request to interact with a discord bot

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord.py, discord-interactions

```
header = {
    'authorization': TOKEN
}

payload = {
        'message_id': message_id['id'],
        'data': {'component_type': 2, 'custom_id': ids[1]}
    }

r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions', data = payload , headers = header)
```

My code so far

getting ERROR --

```
"{\"code\": 50035, \"errors\": {\"application_id\": {\"_errors\": [{\"code\": \"BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED\", \"message\": \"This field is required\"}]}, \"channel_id\": {\"_errors\": [{\"code\": \"BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED\", \"message\": \"This field is required\"}]}, \"type\": {\"_errors\": [{\"code\": \"BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED\", \"message\": \"This field is required\"}]}}, \"message\": \"Invalid Form Body\"}"
```

Please help me how do I tackle this problem and send an api request to interact with a bot.

Comment: Maybe you could explain your code a bit more. I do not really know what kind of API request you are doing/what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is this discord.py? I don't recognise that code. If you are using a fork please tag that fork

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use the API from scratch, which is more difficult and less effective than a library, that already done that for you. Maybe should you use one such as [Nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord), [Hikari](https://github.com/hikari-py/hikari#rest-only-applications) or [PyCord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord) (since [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) is deprecated) unless you have a reason not to.